# VBS script to Automate IE

Tags: authentication, vbscript

I have a script that logs in to a page with the username and password. I am not exactly familiar with VBS but I cannot click on a button that is on the following page (after the login screen). Any suggestions?

```
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Top = 0
objIE.Left = 0
objIE.Width = 1400
objIE.Height = 800
objIE.AddressBar = 0
objIE.StatusBar = 0
objIE.Toolbar = 0
objIE.Visible = True 'We will see the window navigation

objIE.Navigate("http://www.myurl.com/")
Do
Loop Until objIE.ReadyState = 4
objIE.Document.GetElementByID("txtUsername").Value = "Username"
o

bjIE.Document.GetElementByID("txtPassword").Value = "SecurePass"
    objIE.Document.GetElementByID("btnLogon").Click

    WScript.Sleep 5000
objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("btn-text")
```

Here is the HTML:

```html
<td class="btn-text">
 <em unselectable="on" class=""><
   button type="button" id="click-button" class="123-btn">CLICKME</button>
 </em>
```

Comment: Check `msgbox Cstr(objIE.Busy) & objIE.ReadyState & objIE.Document.ReadyState` values before `…("NavigationBarButton").Click`

Comment: @JosefZ It shows `False4complete`

Comment: What about `Set yy=IE.Document.getElementById("NavigationBarButton") :  MsgBox VarType(yy) & " NavigationBarButton " & TypeName(yy)`

Comment: @JosefZ I received the following error: `Object required: 'objIE.Document.GetElementByID(...)'` `800A01A8` Sounds like the NavigationBarButton cannot be found. I will try to analyze this

Comment: Update: Its weird because the ID exists. The ID can be found under a navigation bar, 3rd element..

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add relevant HTML part satisfying [mcve]

Comment: I added the missing HTML that I am trying to access. I can find the `btn-text` but im not sure how to get to click the button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103988/discussion-between-user01230-and-josefz).